# ezpublish/symfony renders 404 in Smarty, everything else in Twig

Tags: php, symfony, smarty, twig, ezpublish

On my eZ publish 5 site I have all my templates in Twig, in the vendor/ezsystems/demobundle/EzSystems/DemoBundle/Resources/views/ subfolders. They are all being used throughout my whole site, no problems there. With one exception: 404 pages. If I go to mysite/nonexistingurl, it gives me a kernel (20) / Error page, with status 404. The template being used for this is the 20.tpl somewhere in eZ publish/symfony, I don't want that, I want to use my own Twig template for this.

How can I achieve this? I added a vendor/ezsystems/demobundle/EzSystems/DemoBundle/Resources/views/Exception/error.html.twig page, but this one is not being called

Comment: are you in dev or prod mode?

Comment: in both modes it's the same

Answer (score 0):

first add this configuration parameter

```
parameters:
    ezpublish_legacy.default.module_default_layout: 'YourBundle::pagelayout_legacy.html.twig'
```

you may add it in the `parameters.yml` file located in `path/to/yourezpublishinstall/ezpublish/config`, the `parameters.yml` is usually imported in the `config.yml` located in the same folder

this would define the twig template located in `path/to/yourbundle/Resources/views/pagelayout_legacy.html.twig` as the parent template for legacy stack modules templates

inside the `pagelayout_legacy.html.twig` template, you may use this code

```
{% extends 'YourBundle::pagelayout.html.twig' %}
{% block content %}
    {# module_result variable is received from the legacy controller. #}
    {% if  module_result.errorCode is defined %}
        <h1>{{ module_result.errorMessage }} ({{ module_result.errorCode }})</h1>
    {% else %}
        {{ module_result.content|raw }}
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

note in the code, the template extends the `pagelayout.html.twig` template, that should here define a block named content, the `pagelayout.html.twig` may usually be the main base layout for your ez publish 5 website
you may modify the `pagelayout_legacy.html.twig` template to your needs

reference:
http://share.ez.no/forums/developer/overriding-legacy-error-pages-templates